# How to enter credentials (Authorize object) in a web service call?

Tags: web-services, matlab, soap, wsdl

I followed the advice [provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14532299/how-to-design-a-soap-call-in-matlab) and it worked like a charm. Right now, I'm connecting to the server and calling a method named *GetFunctionalityTest*. The only input to it is a string, which can be seen in the *GetFunctionalityTest.m* file. So far so good.

Then I attempted to call the real service named *GetSections* whose signature according to the file *GetSections.m* is as follows.

```
function GetSectionsResult = GetSections(obj,auth)
% GetSections(obj,auth)
% Input: auth = (Authorize)
% Output: GetSectionsResult = (ArrayOfString)

values = { auth, };
names = { 'auth', };
types = { '{WSPro.HostingWebservice}Authorize', };

soapMessage = createSoapMessage( ...
  'WSPro.HostingWebservice', ...
  'GetSections', values,names,types,'document');
response = callSoapService( obj.endpoint, ...
  'WSPro.HostingWebservice/GetSections', soapMessage);
GetSectionsResult = parseSoapResponse(response);
```

The definition provided by the server is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=...>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSections xmlns="WSPro.HostingWebservice">
      <auth>
        <uid>string</uid>
        <pw>string</pw>
      </auth>
    </GetSections>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My problem is that I can't specify the authorization syntax-wise. As far I understand, it's supposed to consist of two strings **somehow** but I haven't get it to work. I've tried to compound those as follows.

```
myAuthorization = ['user', 'pass'];
myAuthorization = {'user', 'pass'};
myAuthorization = ['user' 'pass'];
myAuthorization = {'user' 'pass'};
```

Nothing helped. I just got a bunch of errors.

> Error using callSoapService (line 147)
>   Unspecified Fault: SOAP Fault: Server was unable to process request.
>   ---> The parameterized query
>   '(@uid nvarchar(99)) SELECT PassW FROM UserData WHERE UserId = @' expects the parameter '@uid', which was not supplied.

I've browsed all the files automatically created for me and there's no definition of *Authorize* not *ArrayOfString*. I'm guessing it's something that the server defines, since I get no hits on those in MatLab documentation.

1. How can I specify the credentials for authorization?
2. Where can I look up how MatLab maps *Authorization*?

Comment: The SOAP Authentication happens through SOAP Header and not SOAP Body.This link might give you an idea of how SOAP XML should look in case of authentication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998480/web-service-soap-header-authentication

Comment: I got that. But I still need to rely on the methods created for me based on WSDL file. And the second argument to enter is the authorization information. Do I need to rebuild the methods by hand?

Comment: Can you look at the wsdl defintion ? WSDL lookup - hit he service provider's URL followed by "?wsdl" Ex: https://mydomain:port/<Service URI >?wsdl. I am Looking for : <operation name="myOperation">
      <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
      <input><soap:body parts="parameters" use="literal"/>
      <soap:header message="....." ..... use="literal"></soap:header>
    </soap:header>
</input>

Comment: All that's provided by hitting the WSDL file is quoted in the question. Nothing about any operations. I only omitted the envelope-tag but that's default for every call. I also made a call to another places that authorize by a plain string (like a licence key - not a combo of name/pass) and all worked out well. So, basically, I'm starting that's a limitation of MatLab's SOAP management not to be able to handle abstract data types. :(

Answer (score 0):

As noted above:

> The SOAP Authentication happens through SOAP Header and not SOAP Body.This link might give you an idea of how SOAP XML should look in case of authentication :

[Web service soap header authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998480/1113772)