# How to add "Authentication" on existing SOAP web services?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, authentication, soap

I have SOAP web-service named "getApplicationDetails" which is deployed and used by few applications (which are in my office network)

Now the above service should be allowed to be used by applications which are outside of my office network which in turn means that I need to add user authentication which seems to fair enough from this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998480/web-service-soap-header-authentication)

Instead of creating a new web service can I use existing web services by passing authentication in predefined cases and use authentication in rest.

- What should be approach for the above scenario ?
- Do I need to consider spring AOP ?
  (*From my memory, I can recall that the logging,authentication etc can be moved to external classes with this approach*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/index.html) it has out-of-the-box HTTP basic authentication and integration with SOAP and spring and what not...

Comment: thanks for the library never heard of it, I will take a look  and post the comments here. I will wait for further answers without using any external library.